# If $R[x]$ is a PID, $R$ necessarily has to be a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

It is given that R is a commutative ring with identity.

My attempt: I tried to get a contradiction. Given a nonunit $a \in R$, I wanted to show that $(a,x)$ is not a principal ideal in 
$R[x]$. Then, by being PID, $(a,x)=(b(x))$ where $ b(x) \in R[x]$. But I do not know how to go on from here.

Comment: If $(a, x) = (b(x))$ then consider the degree of $b(x).$ Since this is in a PID, we have that $b(x)$ must be a constant polynomial (why?).This would then imply that $b$ is a unit as you have $x \in (b(x)),$ i.e. there must be some $cx \in R[x]$ such that $bcx = x.$ Hence, we can conclude $a$ is a unit - contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a PID, every prime ideal is maximal. Here $(x)$ is a prime ideal and hence a  maximal ideal. Thus  $R[x]/(x)$ is a field. But this field is nothing but....?